# Type conversion failure in update query

Tags: sql, type-conversion, ms-access-2007

I'm fairly new to Access so this is driving me a little crazy.

I'm creating an inventory database and want to count the number of items in stock to update an ordering form. Received items are assigned an order code, and I want to count the number of instances of each order code found within the master table. I have a make table query which does this just fine:

```
SELECT PrimerList.PrimerName
    , First(Primer_Master.FR) AS FR
    , Primer_Master.OrderCode
    , Count(Primer_Master.OrderCode) AS InStock
INTO PrimerOrder
FROM PrimerList
LEFT JOIN Primer_Master ON PrimerList.ID = Primer_Master.PrimerName
GROUP BY PrimerList.PrimerName
        , Primer_Master.OrderCode
        , Primer_Master.PrimerName
        , Primer_Master.FR
        , Primer_Master.Finished
HAVING ((([Primer_Master]![Finished])=No));
```

I want to use PrimerOrder to update an order list table PrimerOrderList which has all of the different possible order codes, updating the InStock value for records with matching OrderCode:

```
UPDATE PrimerOrderList 
SET PrimerOrderList.InStock = PrimerOrder.InStock
WHERE (((PrimerOrderList.OrderCode)=[PrimerOrder].[OrderCode]));
```

However, when I try to run it I get parameter boxes which pop-up asking for PrimerOrder.OrderCode and PrimerOrderList.OrderCode. Even if I put in a valid value for each, I get a type conversion failure. I've checked the data types for both tables and don't see how there could be a type conversion failure - both are set to text.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the PrimerOrder table in your query. Should be:

```
UPDATE PrimerOrderList INNER JOIN PrimerOrder 
ON PrimerOrderList.OrderCode = PrimerOrder.OrderCode
PrimerOrderList.InStock = PrimerOrder.InStock
```